# Python While Loop with Function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop

My professor is asking for us to output the example on the left (word doc). My current code is on the right. He wants us to use a While/For loop in the code. I made the current code with only the 15% displayed (middle idle), but I do not know how to add the 20%,25%. Is this possible? [Current code in screen clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oontr.png)

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a list of tip percent options I would suggest setting up something like this:

```
tip_percent_options = [0.15, 0.2, 0.25]

for tip_percent in tip_percent_options:
     
     # do the things you want to do with each tip option. Pass it to your tip_function etc.
     print(tip_percent)
```

Some [examples of how to use loops here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 0):

honestly dude, just do your homework the right way. Even if you're not trying to become a dev you'll be so much better off in every STEM related field if you have these skills...

but anyways, like your prof. said you want to use a for or while loop to iterate through the tip amounts by a percentage of 5.

Here's a simple example to help you along where you appear to be stuck:

```
def main ():
    tip = 0
    iterator = 5
    while tip <= 25:
        print(tip)
        # += is shorthand for 'tip = tip + iterator'
        tip += iterator


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
0
5
10
15
20
25
```

Implement something like this, or the 'for' loop example the other guy demonstrated into what you have and you should be set

Comment: Replace the while with "for tip in range(15, 30, 5):". Then you can get rid of initializing tip to 0, and needing an extra line of code in the loop to increment it.

Comment: sure you're right... that's definitely a more optimal way. I was trying to demonstrate the concept of looping/iterating simply for this guy

Comment: Range is a bit confusing to look at if you're learning how to loop/iterate in python. But the incrementing a variable in a loop thing should almost never be done in python. It illustrates how loops work, but not how to use looping....